# cx_freeze/PyQt5: pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I do have a cx_freeze issue on python 3.7.6.4 ond Windows 10 (also tried Windows 7 - same error) - using this makeexe:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "sys"],
                     "include_files": ["DMCA.ico"]
}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "DMCA",
        version = "0.01",
        description = "DMCA by EP",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("DMCA.py", base=base, icon="DMCA.ico")])
```

I do get:

```
C:\WPy64-3760\Code\09Working>makeexe

C:\WPy64-3760\Code\09Working>C:/WPy64-3760/python-3.7.6.amd64/python MakeExe.py build
running build
running build_exe
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\DMCA.exe
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\python37.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\python37.dll
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\VCRUNTIME140.dll
error: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden: 'build\\exe.win-amd64-3.7\\DMCA.exe'
```

and if I use:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "sys"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "DMCA",
        version = "0.01",
        description = "DMCA by EP",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("DMCA.py", base=base)])
```

The error is:

```
C:\WPy64-3760\Code\09Working>makeexe

C:\WPy64-3760\Code\09Working>C:/WPy64-3760/python-3.7.6.amd64/python MakeExe.py build
running build
running build_exe
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\DMCA.exe
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\python37.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\python37.dll
copying C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\VCRUNTIME140.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MakeExe.py", line 21, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("DMCA.py", base=base)])
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 348, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 617, in Freeze
    self._FreezeExecutable(executable)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 208, in _FreezeExecutable
    self._AddVersionResource(exe)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 143, in _AddVersionResource
    stamp(fileName, versionInfo)
  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32verstamp.py", line 163, in stamp
    h = BeginUpdateResource(pathname, 0)
pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', The system cannot find the file specified.)
```

how can I find the problem?
The source code, which I want to freeze is larger; PyQt QmainWindow and multiple sub-files using matplotlib 3.2.1, pillow 6.2.1, scipy 1.4.1 and numpy 1.17.4+mkl, so it would overwhelm this page. I also tried to add my sub-files to build_exe_options as 'includes' and output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setup new Python and installing the packages solved this issue, nevertheless the executable is not working properly. Closing this  issue.